# Some Session variables become empty / null between pages

Tags: php, session

Something odd is going on. I have been testing a web application on my local machine and it works perfectly fine. Session's are being handled perfectly.

Recently, when I promoted the application to production, everything works well except the **some** of the session variables not being saved between pages.

It seems like all of the newly created session variables that I have added to the application are NOT being saved between pages and all the ones that already existed before the changes were made, ARE being saved between pages.

I was thinking maybe it has something to do with the `php.ini` or some security setting perhaps? What makes this hard for me to troubleshoot is that SOME but not all SESSION's are being lost between pages.

The 1st page nav contains all SESSION vars as needed, 10 session vars. 
All of the new vars that were created and saved on the first page become null / empty on the any page other than the first and the number of SESSION vars drops to 9.

I greatly appreciate any advice on what is causing this problem and how to troubleshoot this problem!

**NOTE:** the last four variables are newly created, all others have existed before the new changes.

Page Nav 1:

```
echo 'ID: ' . session_id() . ' <br/><br/>';
        echo 'SAVE PATH: ' . session_save_path() . ' <br/><br/>';
        var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Output

```
ID: 8rd3paua61caaqd09ahoc0km42

SAVE PATH: D:\php5\session

array(10) { ["termstamp"]=> int(1383577150) ["timestamp"]=> int(1383577150) ["tm"]=> int(1383577150) ["userid"]=> string(6) "153355" ["authenticated"]=> bool(true) ["auth"]=> bool(true) ["joinMeta"]=> string(0) "" ["selectMeta"]=> string(0) "" ["search_queryyy"]=> array(12) { [0]=> string(27) "sec.lastname LIKE '%smith%'" [1]=> string(0) "" [2]=> string(0) "" [3]=> string(0) "" [4]=> string(0) "" [5]=> string(0) "" [6]=> string(0) "" [7]=> string(43) "sec.has_status != 99 && sec.has_status != 6" [8]=> string(0) "" [9]=> string(0) "" [10]=> string(0) "" [11]=> string(0) "" } ["testtttttt"]=> string(17) "SOMETHING INTO IT" }
```

Page Nav 2 and greater:

```
echo 'ID: ' . session_id() . ' <br/><br/>';
        echo 'SAVE PATH: ' . session_save_path() . ' <br/><br/>';
        var_dump($_SESSION);
```

Output:

```
ID: 8rd3paua61caaqd09ahoc0km42

SAVE PATH: D:\php5\session

array(10) { ["termstamp"]=> int(1383577150) ["timestamp"]=> int(1383577150) ["tm"]=> int(1383577150) ["userid"]=> string(6) "153355" ["authenticated"]=> bool(true) ["auth"]=> bool(true) ["joinMeta"]=> string(0) "" ["selectMeta"]=> string(0) "" ["search_queryyy"]=> NULL ["testtttttt"]=> string(17) "SOMETHING INTO IT" }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no relevant code block. I am doing a simple `session_start()`, `$_SESSION['test'] = 'hello'`. It is saved on the first page of the page nav but lost on any others. This problem only exists on production, not on test.

Comment: do you use balancer (several phisical servers) or you have only one server ?

Comment: Do you have the session_start() in all your php scripts?

Comment: well, does your PHPSESSID cookie value change ?

Comment: When I do echo `session_id();` on the first page it outputs the session ID, on the second page it echo's nothing, but still keeps the old session variable's just not the new ones I created. The session variables are saved between pages, but the contents of the vars become empty / Null after the first nav page.

Comment: Please see edited, I added some additional info.

Comment: I accidentally blocked session variables on the firewall on my virgin router. Is that it?

Comment: Session variables are created and saved between pages, only problem is they become null / empty after the first page.

Comment: Weird thing is, if you note the `testtt` session variable is also newly created and it is saved and does not become null / empty between pages.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend Did you find a solution to this problem? I sort of have the same issue since 2 days

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered storing these values in `input type="hidden"` fields as a backup plan?

Work on a variation from this, perhaps this will push you in the right direction and see where it goes wrong.

```
<?php
    foreach ($_SESSION as $key=>$value)
    {
?>
       <input type="hidden" name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $value; ?>" />
<?php
    }
?>
```

***Note:** Code untested and will probably not work, but you get the picture...*

Comment: Oh ye.. let's make the session available for hijacking.. What if someone will edit the value of the fields? Where will that take us?

Comment: This was only a suggestion, and nothing says we *have* to use this method. The original intention was to validate that the information is being sent; if this doesn't work, the problem could be the session itself, not the data.

Answer (score 0):

If you have session variables working on one page and not on others it means that (most probably) you lack **session_start()** on those other pages.

Comment: All the pages contain `session_start()`. This is not the problem. Thanks anyways.

Comment: To replicate your issue - create 2 php files to show your scenario and update a question as problam may be in completely other place than you think.

Comment: Do you have custom session handlers or you use default one?

Comment: Perhaps they are custom ( i think they are), however, the same exact custom session handlers are used on the testing server and this problem is non-existent there.

Comment: @AnchovyLegend: For tests do 1) reboot your browser to create another session 2) in page 1 - add unset($_SESSION) after your session_start() followed by a few $_SESSION['blabla'] = ... and show results. If these differ - I'll believe your sessions do not work

Comment: What do you mean? if I unset session, obviously session variables will be lost, maybe I'm not understanding the test.

Comment: Just confirmed: **ALL new session variables are not being saved between pages.**

Comment: Yes - unset and set (only in one file) them and show results of $_SESSION dump from both files

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40511/discussion-between-anchovylegend-and-artur)